# mysql - create trigger that duplicates row in a different table without specifying each column

Tags: mysql, sql

I made an insert trigger that duplicates the row in a different table. Right now it looks like this:

```
delimiter #
create trigger SomeTriggerName after insert on someTable1
   for each row
   begin
   insert into someTable2(id, column1, etc., etc.) values (new.id, new.column1, new.etc, new.etc)
   end#
```

However, I know that the second table has the exact structure as the first one. So... is there anyway to insert it without naming each column?

I tried setting "new" as a row directly, but it said "unknown column new".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The second table has the exact structure as the first one. So... is
> there anyway to insert it without naming each column?

Yes; You can do it as below :

```
CREATE TRIGGER SomeTriggerName AFTER INSERT ON someTable1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO someTable2
  SELECT * FROM someTable1 WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

I assume, you have a unique column or an id auto_increment.

If you don't have a unique column or an auto-increment column to use as a reference, you can use the [LAST_INSERT_ID() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) to get the ID of the last inserted row in someTable2, and use that ID to insert the new row in someTable2.

```
CREATE TRIGGER SomeTriggerName AFTER INSERT ON someTable1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO someTable2
  SELECT * FROM someTable1 WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END;
```

If you don't have a unique way to identify the row, then you can use a combination of columns that together form a unique key.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER INSERT ON someTable1
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
       INSERT INTO someTable2 SELECT * FROM someTable1 WHERE col1 = NEW.col1 AND col2 = NEW.col2 AND col3 = NEW.col3;
  END;
```

If you don't have a unique way to identify the row and you can't use a combination of columns to do so, then you may want to consider generating a unique identifier for each row in the original table, and using that identifier to identify the corresponding row in the second table.

One way to generate a unique identifier is to use the [UUID() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid), which returns a Universally Unique Identifier (UUID).

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER INSERT ON someTable1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @uuid = UUID();
    INSERT INTO someTable2 SET uuid = @uuid, col1 = NEW.col1, col2 = NEW.col2, col3 = NEW.col3;
END;
```

Comment: Not quite right. This insert all the values from new table to someTable2 after every insert on someTable1 unless the table has a unique column or an id auto_increment and you use it on a where condition. `SELECT * FROM new where id=new.id`

Comment: @ErgestBasha. Yup, You are absolutely right.
I modified the trigger. Thank You :)

Comment: While the answer is 100% correct (+1 for that :D)... I can't count of having an unique way to identify the row back; I can't assume either synthetic pk, either natural one (the background is that I am trying to generate a set of triggers that will hold a group of tables updated with the original). Is there any other way?

Comment: I don't think this solves the issue. That creates a "link" between the records, but I still have to name columns manually.

Background reasoning: I am trying to keep 2 tables, of abstract structure (can be anything) in sync. The only thing I know for sure is that both tables exist, and that they have the exact same structure.

Comment: I know what I do... I get the columns from schema in a cursor, and generate an output with the query in full... the problem is that I need to run a result of a query and mysql is not so fund of that. But I can throw it into a stored proc and run that. Super convoluted... was hoping I can use NEW as a normal set of variables :(.

Comment: Nope... can't do that either because it would mean that I create the trigger from a stored routine and that is not allowed :|. I'll just make a script. Was hoping for a pure sql solution but is not worth the hustle.

Comment: @zozo you have the answer to your question. Open another thread if you have another question and please read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) to make a accurate explanation of the issue you are facing